# Obtaining Schematic: Jeeves in WoW

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm having a difficult time figuring out the easiest way to get my hands on [Schematic: Jeeves](http://www.wowhead.com/item=49050/schematic-jeeves).

Do I need to raise my skinning skills and farm it myself? There are none on my server in the AH either (not sure if it's BoP or what).

Assuming I don't have skinning, what's the easiest way to get this schematic? I don't mind farming, but I really don't want to get skinning to 525.

Comment: What's this to do skinning? It's an engineering only item.... The page clearly shows a list of mechanical NPCs that this schematic can be salvaged from as well a list that can drop the schematic. And since it's BoP, you will just have to farm for it.

Comment: I think you might have confused salvaging with skinning - see here: http://www.wowpedia.org/Mob_engineering

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need the skinning profession to salvage from a mechanical mob.

Salvaging, or mob engineering, is an innate ability that comes from taking up the engineering profession and can be performed only on mechanical mobs. It works similarly to skinning, in that, you right-click on the mob you just looted a second time for profession-specific loot (other similar loot abilities are mining on stone golem type mobs (mining) and herb-collection on bog lord type mobs (herbalism)).

The only way to loot this schematic right now (as of 4.3.4) is to farm for it yourself on mechanical mobs. They have a chance to give you the schematic when you loot or salvage them. The wowhead page you provided gives you a comprehensive list of mobs that drop this, so I am not going to repeat it here. As it is bound on pickup, you won't find it in the AH.